# What would you call an Intermediary REST layer that uses external APIs?

Tags: rest, api, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

Hey guys I need general help with identifying what an intermediate REST layer is called.

I am developing a solution that relies on the user data of a video game company. The company has REST APIs that I can call to gather the data, and I have decided to take the following approach: build a website with React, build an intermediate layer using Spring-boot which will provide APIs for the website and also call the company's APIs to gather the data. Say I want to research best practices for that intermediate layer be it caching for example, I am having trouble narrowing my search down to specifically cater for my architecture.

So what would you call that intermediate solution?

If you think I have design flaws, advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It’s a service layer or thin proxy. I mean, it’s no different than any other layer that makes external calls.

Comment: What do you call a Website that uses data exposed on an other Website? In the end it is still a Website no matter what

Answer (score 0):

Since, your application is acting as a think layer of proxy a **[backend for frontend application architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/backends-for-frontends)** (BFF) might fit better.

A BFF is, in simple terms, a layer between the user experience and the resources it calls on. When a mobile user requests data, in a BFF situation, their request is translated through the BFF and into a general layer below it.

Comment: I find the abbreviation BFF in this link quite funny as in RL most would understand something like best friend forever for such an abbreviation what also somehow describes the usual (more or less tight) coupling between backend and frontend. Note though that you should summarize the content of this link as such links may get broken over time and thus the content isn't reachable further

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've added a line to explain BFF on a high level.